# How to password protect a zip file with objective-zip and CRC32?

Tags: objective-c, zip, password-encryption, crc32, objectivezip

I am trying to password-protect a zip file I create with Objective-zip. It requires a crc32 from me, but I just do not seem to be able to make it work, everytime I unzip it (with "The Unarchiver"), I get *'wrong password'* etc.

I have looked around on here and although I was able to find some stuff, I could not find anything helpful, so I thought it okay to open a new question.

This is my code so far:

```
//file i want to zip
NSString *path = @"/Users/dominik/Coding/zipthis.txt";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Objective Zip Stream
OZZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"fileInZip.txt" fileDate:[NSDate date] compressionLevel:OZZipCompressionLevelBest password:@"password" crc32:result];

//I don't know what this log does
    NSLog(@"CRC32: %lu", result);
```

Any suggestions?